# What is the edition/version of this book (Pensées De Pascal)?

Tags: literature, book

**Full Title:**

```
Pensées De Pascal

précédées de sa vie

Par Mme Perier, Sa Soeur

Suivies D'Un Choix

Des Pensées De Nicole

Et De Son Traité De La Paix Avec Les Hommes
```

(This is all one of the first pages)

At the bottom of the same page, it says:

```
Paris, Librairie De Firmin Didot Frères,
Imprimeurs De L'institut,
Rue Jacob, 56

1847
```

(Excuse spelling errors above please)

With that out of the way, I've researched every bit of this information. The date at the bottom did come up with some editions, but not the one I have. Researching the Librairie De Firmin Didot...etc. also came up with some information, but I also didn't have any luck finding the exact version I have.

**Physical Information:**
On the binding, it says Pascal with a small line underneath. It appears to be leather bound. The pattern on the binding is a brown background with black and gold stripes at different intervals. The pattern on the cover is tan and black swirls as well as the back.

There is some cursive writing on one of the pages before the actual book starts. As far as I can decipher, it is written like this:

```
Elizabeth L. Burling -
     Well Logan Square

M L. Price

New Year's 1852 (the date is kind of hard to read)
```

I do not know if that is relevant. A quick search of the names did not return any satisfying results.

I can give any other relevant information. As aforementioned, I have found editions that look vaguely similar in appearance, but none with the described colors or other notable figures.

I am somewhat aware of the history of the book, so in this case I'm mostly interested in knowing the actual history of the edition I have and if it's worth anything.

Comment: I am not sure if this is on topic for history.se, but I think you should put up a picture or two rather than rely purely on textual descriptions.

Comment: Welcome to history.SE! I've formatted your question a bit, and fixed a couple of possible spelling mistakes in the 1st page transcription.

Comment: What are you actually asking? This is an edition of Pascal published by Firmin Didot Frères in 1847. Are you asking how much you can sell it for?

Comment: I was mostly interested in knowing what I had. I doubt it's worth much, but I will tell you it's in fair condition if you want to give me a rough idea.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Does your edition has XXXVI + 504 pages. Does it have the year 1848 printed somewhere, probably at the end?